# Add AWS Cognito to angular application

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have an existing Angular app that uses angular-oauth2-oidc to connect to our own Identity Server for authentication.
We now want to use Cognito for authentication and keep out API and Angular app on our own server.
How do I setup amplify and auth for this existing angular app? I can only find examples for setting up new apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add amplify to an existing project using the same steps as in a new app. Navigate to the root of your project and run the following commands:

```
amplify configure
amplify init
amplify add auth
amplify push
```

You can follow the [official docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/js) from this point.